# Objective-C - When I add a subview, my subview is going out of the screen at the bottom. Misunderstanding of frames?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, frame, cgrect

Im practicing objective-C, and I try to do everything programmatically.

I'm making a simple view that I add on my view of the ViewController, but this subview is going out of the screen. 
When I set my frame, the position for the X and Y are respected, but the rest, no...

Here is the screenshot of my result :
[image]

As you can see... The red subview is going out of the screen.

Here is my `loadView` where I add that subview :

HomeViewController.m - loadView

```
-(void)loadView
{
    self.view = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:[UIScreen mainScreen].bounds];

    UIView *subview = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(15, 15, self.view.frame.size.width - 30, self.view.frame.size.height - 30)];
    [subview setBackgroundColor:[UIColor redColor]];
    [self.view addSubview:subview];
}
```

For the padding, I did put 15 for the position `x` and `y`... And for the frame, I did calculate with the size of the `self.view` by removing paddings... As you see, it works well for the `width`, but for the `height`, it is a big fail. It goes outside the screen.

In my `AppDelegate.h`, I set the `navigationController.navigationBar.translucent = NO;`, in order to that when I set position for `x`, and `y`, it starts well after the `navigationBar` .

I don't understand this weird behavior for the height... If someone has a good explanation for this please.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you shouldn't rely on the value of `self.view` in `viewDidLoad`. It is set to a correct value later, in `viewWillAppear:`. You can keep your code, if you make your subview resize automatically when `self.view` is displayed. For that, set `autoresizingMask` on the subview:

```
subview.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight;
```

(or add an equivalent set of constraints if you use Auto Layout.)

Also, I recommend to use `bounds` instead of `frame`:

```
UIView *subview = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(15, 15, self.view.bounds.size.width - 30, self.view.bounds.size.height - 30)];
```

It doesn't make a difference here, but it often does, e.g. if you calculate the frame's `x` and `y` based on the parent frame.

Comment: I tried subview.autoresizingMask but it didn't work. I'm using Xcode 6 and building on iOS 8.3. I created a very simple project called TestComponent, dragged an UITextView into the ViewController. I put the code line subview.autoresizingMask into viewWillAppear method of ViewController.m. When I started the app, the textview was not auto sized. My project is on github: https://github.com/minhquan/iOSPractice/tree/master/TestComponent Could you please glance and see what happened? Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1):

`loadView` method just creates the view. At the point when `loadView` gets called there is no information about final view frame hence its children views cannot be placed properly.

The right place to update your children views' frames is `viewDidLayoutSubviews`:

```
- (void)viewDidLayoutSubviews {
    [super viewDidLayoutSubviews];
    // update child view frame here
}
```

**Remarks:** you can define auto-layout constraints of your child view in code and they will be automatically applied to child views when view controller's view gets resized.